# Flame sensor and MQ2 sensor not working with Esp8266?

Tags: esp8266

When ever flame is detected sms will be send this is what i am doing,but the  flame and smoke sensor works awesome when they are tested seperately(Without Esp8266) when they are integrated with Esp8266 they are not at all responding to the flame or smoke . I have tested flame Sensor with serial monitor the values are 150,148,147,......
When it is tested without Esp8266 it has given 1000,996.....(Without Flame)
52,64,38.....(With Flame )

[image: Wifi Connection to Arduino]

Flame sensor Connections:
VCC : 5V
GND : GND
D0 : 7`

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char *ssid = "NUS_006"; 
const char *password = "shankar006";
int flame=7;  
void setup() {
    delay(1000);
    pinMode(flame,INPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);        
    delay(1000);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);       
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
           delay(500);
           Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Flame= ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(flame));
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: your sketch is for the esp8266. you have an esp-01 module like on the picture? you wired the sensors to Uno and expect that the esp8266 sketch will read them by some magic?

Comment: thanks for responding so what should i do to read the sensor values?-Juraj

Comment: do you have an esp-01 module? then you can't connect sensors to it and you must work with sensors in Uno. put some firmware into esp-01 and use it as WiFi adapter. (or create your own 'firmware')